# Why do grindstones produce a finer finish than sandpaper?

Tags: sanding

I don't understand why a grinding stone seems to produce a much finer finish than the same grit of sandpaper.

For example, if I grind a piece of metal with an 80 grit silicon carbide grinding stone with a vitrified bond it has an almost mirror finish, but if use 80 grit sandpaper on the same metal it looks all scratched up. What's the difference?

Comment: Are you using the same method to apply both abrasives?

Answer (score 1):

A grinding wheel is a fundamentally different tool and is self shaping.  Whereas sandpaper has protruding edges at the resolution of the grit that tend to be lost in whole pieces as the paper wears, the grinding stone instead has a more or less flat surface with voids at the correct resolution.  The other factor is that the grinding stone works at a much higher velocity, which allows it to remove less material per pass than the sand paper, averaging out whatever gouges it creates and functioning the way a higher grit would at a lower velocity.  Even with sandpaper, you will find you can get a finer finish with gentle sanding than with rough.  If you use a sanding wheel to compare, you'll likely have much more similar results, and it also helps to pre-wear the sandpaper before sanding something fine.  When particles come loose from sandpaper they also tend to gouge.  When I'm wet sanding opal, whatever grit I'm using, I abuse the sandpaper a bit first with a suitably soft but less expensive stone to get rid of loose bits and jaggies.  I also have a 4000 grit diamond stone and a 600 grit Arkansas dry stone.  If I wet grind with the Arkansas dry stone, I can actually get a finer finish than with the 4000 grit diamond stone by utilizing the slurry that builds up as I grind, which functions as a much finer than 600 grit polishing paste.

400 grit is about 22 microns big, but if you spin it fast enough, you may only be using the outer 5 or less microns for example.

Comment: So a grind stone texture is quantified by cavities compared to sand paper which is quantified by protrusions? Interesting, that alone makes for a notable difference in result.

Comment: @p2000 with the caveats that the softer vitrifying material may count as void for this purpose despite being a solid and actual particle density in the grinding wheel may be higher due to the multilayer stack up of abrasive particles.  The comparison isn't perfect but as I say, they are fundamentally different tools.

Answer (score 1):

11,000 rpm is the difference. There's also the uniformity of the grindstone, when sandpaper grit falls away, there's nothing to back it up and suddenly one section is getting a little more abrasion from the grit piling up than the rest and it shows up as a sweeps.

Now if you're talking grinding stone on an angle grinder and flap disc on an angle grinder, taking rpm out of the picture, the uniformity still plays.

They also do different things, a grinding stone is less aggressive because of this uniformity. It doesn't clear as freely, but in freeing waste more quickly the sand paper also loses it's grit in the process.